# Python: Draw a second y-axis on pyplot figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a subplot that consists of two figures. Each of the figures shows some data plotted vs a time axis. And for each figure I want to have two y axes corresponding to two different graphs shown within the same figure.

Let's start with the data corresponding to one of the y-axes. This data is the same for each of the two figures and is generated as follows (it is fairly ugly code and if you have any suggestions as on how to improve it, please let me know!):

```
pwm_len = len(Time)/6
pwm_max = 255
pwm_min = 150
pwm_mid = 200
pwm_zero = 0
pwm1 = np.repeat(pwm_max, pwm_len) 
pwm2 = np.repeat(pwm_min, pwm_len)
pwm3 = np.repeat(pwm_max, pwm_len)
pwm4 = np.repeat(pwm_mid, pwm_len)
pwm5 = np.repeat(pwm_max, pwm_len)
pwm6 = np.repeat(pwm_zero, pwm_len)
pwm = pwm1 + pwm2 + pwm3 + pwm4 + pwm5 + pwm6
```

To create the figure, I am using the following code (please note that it is not working right now, due to some wrong usage of `twinx()` ):

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
axs_pwm = axs.twinx()
axs[0].plot(Time, velocity, 'b-')
axs_pwm[0].plot(Time, pwm, 'r-')
axs[0].set_ylabel('[mm/s]')
axs_pwm[0].set_ylabel('PWM')
axs[0].grid(True)
axs[1].plot(Time, velocity_filtered, 'b-')
axs_pwm[1].plot(Time, pwm, 'r-')
axs[1].set_ylabel('[mm/s]')
axs_pwm[1]-set_ylabel('PWM')
axs[1].grid(True)

plt.show()
```

apparently I am using the `twinx()` function in a wrong way. But what is a different way to draw the second y axis?

Comment: A twin axes is created from one axes, `ax.twinx()` where `ax` is a `matplotlib.axes.Axes`. So similar to how `axs.plot` wouldn't work, `axs.twinx()` doesn't work either.

Comment: Well, [indeed](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernest)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest : Oh, Herr Ernest. Now I see :)

Comment: @SpghttCd : There should be a get together of matplotlib users once in a while  to know people more ;)

Comment: @Sheldore Definitely, could be interesting (or irritating, or...) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending upon [ImportanceOfBeingErnest's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)'s suggestion, you need the following:

- Create the twin axis for each subplot using the index 0 and 1 while using `twinx()`
- Use the respective twin axis' object to plot data and set y-axis labels

---

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

axs_pwm1 = axs[0].twinx() # Create twin axis for the first subplot
axs[0].plot(Time, velocity, 'b-')
axs_pwm1.plot(Time, pwm, 'r-')
axs[0].set_ylabel('[mm/s]')
axs_pwm1.set_ylabel('PWM')
axs[0].grid(True)

axs_pwm2 = axs[1].twinx() # Create twin axis for the second subplot
axs[1].plot(Time, velocity_filtered, 'b-')
axs_pwm2.plot(Time, pwm, 'r-')
axs[1].set_ylabel('[mm/s]')
axs_pwm2.set_ylabel('PWM')
axs[1].grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Or as suggested by @SpghttCd in the comments, you can predefine all the twin axis and then use index as

```
ax2 = [ax.twinx() for ax in axs]

ax2[0].plot(...)
ax2[1].plot(...)
```

Comment: Perhaps for achieving the same interface (i.e. list of axes) for the secondary axes as for the primary axes, one could create all at once by a LC: `ax2 = [ax.twinx() for ax in axs]`. Might additionally lead to slightly better readability (that's also why I chose the three letter name `ax2` instead of e.g. `sec_axs`). And would help the more the more subplots there are